# CMDT CSV Insert Problems

Tags: salesforcedx, custom-metadata, csv, insert, cli

Am trying to insert new records for a custom metadata file and saw that force:cmdt:record:insert has been deprecated. I tried sf cmdt generate records --csv path/to/my.csv --type-name MyCmdt but VS Code is saying the command doesnt exist. It will even suggest generate metadata sobject but then say its a beta command and can't be used. I am at a lost. I tried the deprecated commands too and depending on whether I use the deprecated flag names or the new ones, I kept getting these errors:

Error (1): Unexpected arguments: —-csv, /csvpath/, —-output-directory, /cmdtpath/, --input-directory, /newrecordsfolder/

Error (1): Unexpected arguments: —-filepath, /csvpath/, —-outputdir, /cmdtpath/, --inputdir, /newrecordsfolder/
See more help with --help

Notes:

/csvpath/ I am trying to retrieve from desktop and copied the path directly
/cmdtpath/ and /newrecordsfolder/ I tried both relative and just the path

What am I doing wrong???

Edit:
Oh sometimes I get this error as well...

Error (1): ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/Documents/Folder/main/default/objects/test__mdt/test__mdt/fields'